# Read, modify, and display .STL file 3D model using c#

Tags: c#, 3d-modelling

I used Solidworks to build a 3D model and save as a .STL file. I would like to use C# to read the file and change the data while displaying the model.

Can any one give me some references?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may user batu92k's [STL Viewer](https://github.com/batu92k/STL-Viewer).
Project url is below.

https://github.com/batu92k/STL-Viewer

And also you may open stl in a text editor and modify the file by changing related parameters.